# swift: How to set UITableViewCell display fullscreen with InfiniteScrolling (allow paging)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, fullscreen

I have a custom `UITableView` with infinite Scroll and Paging Enable. Each of my cells has `UIImageView` on background, I want each time I scroll up or down it will display each image as full screen.

I used this function for full screen, but my view is not full screen after one time infinite scroll.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return self.view.frame.size.height
}
```

Comment: Post ur full tableview methods code and screenshot for ur design how u need.

Answer (score 2):

Late Answer, Might help to others.
For Full-screen Paging of your TableViewcell. Follow the below steps.

> (Consider as Without navigation bar)

1. TableView constrain should be with superview (not safeArea) in allside with 0 constant.
   [image]

2. configure your Tableview like below.

   override func viewDidLoad() {

   ```
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureTableView()
   ```

   }

   private func configureTableView() {

   ```
        tableView.rowHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.isPagingEnabled = true
        tableView.bounces = false
        tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
        tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
        tableView.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
        tableView.sectionFooterHeight = CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
        tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
   ```

Comment: Just added your code. Works perfect. thank you for the detail answer.

Comment: Happy Coding @Umair_UAS

Answer (score 0):

Please find below source code in which you will get table view scrolling along with the different images.

**Swift 4**

```
    //
    //  ImageTVC.swift
    //
    //  Created by Test User on 06/02/18.
    //  Copyright © 2018. All rights reserved.
    //

    import UIKit

    class ImageTVC: UITableViewCell {

        @IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView!

        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
            // Initialization code
        }

        override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
            super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

            // Configure the view for the selected state
        }

    }



    //
    //  TableViewVC.swift
    //
    //  Created by Test User on 06/02/18.
    //  Copyright © 2018. All rights reserved.
    //


    class TableViewVC: UIViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        }
    }

    extension TableViewVC: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 100
        }

        //----------------------------------------------------------------

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ImageCell") as! ImageTVC

            if indexPath.item % 2 == 0 {

                cell.imgView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(indexPath.item * 2)/255.0, green: CGFloat(indexPath.item * 0)/255.0, blue: CGFloat(indexPath.item * 0)/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

            } else if indexPath.item % 3 == 0 {

                cell.imgView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(indexPath.item * 0)/255.0, green: CGFloat(indexPath.item * 2)/255.0, blue: CGFloat(indexPath.item * 0)/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

            } else {

                cell.imgView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(indexPath.item * 0)/255.0, green: CGFloat(indexPath.item * 0)/255.0, blue: CGFloat(indexPath.item * 2)/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
            }

            print("IndexPath.row = \(indexPath.row)")

            return cell
        }

        //----------------------------------------------------------------

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            return tableView.bounds.size.height
        }
    }
```

Also find storyboard design.

[image]

Comment: paging is ok in the begin. but paging is not fit after being second infinite scroll

Comment: I have prepared a demo in which i have tested it and it's working perfect after n number of infinite scroll.

Comment: in my infinite data load from web by json. 10 data come in a time.

Comment: If you can share your code then i can provide your fix of it!

Comment: I would appreciate i you could accept my answer, as it's quite relevant to your requirement!

Comment: I am really sorry

Comment: Brother! please come to on this Question. i want to Flip Cell between two UITableViewCell https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48720442/swift-how-to-flip-cell-between-two-uitableviewcell/48729654?noredirect=1#comment84467213_48729654

Comment: Sure sister will look into your question.

Comment: You got any solution ? if you find than please tell me .I have same issue