# swift: How to Flip Cell between two UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, flip

I have two `UITableViewCell` in a `UITableViewController`.

I want to flip indexPaths on click didSelect method.

When I will click indextPath.row “0” in tableViewCellOne it will show indexPath.row “0” of tableViewCellTwo.

Now it is not flip properly. Also crash apps after click a few time on didSelect method.

Error message is:

> //Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempted to dequeue multiple cells for the same index path, which is not allowed. If you really need to dequeue more cells than the table view is requesting, use the -dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: method (without an index path). Cell identifier: FlipTableViewCellZero, index path:

```
var isOpen = true

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if isOpen{

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FlipTableViewCellZero", for: indexPath) as! FlipTableViewCellZero

        var categoryObject = arrNewsList[indexPath.section]

        cell.profileImage = categoryObject[indexPath.row].textView
        return cell

    }else{

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FlipTableViewCellOne", for: indexPath) as! FlipTableViewCellOne

        var categoryObject = arrNewsList[indexPath.section]

        cell.newsTextView.text = categoryObject[indexPath.row].details

        return cell

    }
    return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FlipTableViewCellZero", for: indexPath)

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    isOpen = true

    let selectedCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FlipTableViewCellOne", for: indexPath) as! FlipTableViewCellOne
    UIView.transition(with: selectedCell, duration: 0.6, options: .transitionFlipFromLeft, animations: nil, completion: nil)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    isOpen = false

    let deselectedCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FlipTableViewCellZero", for: indexPath) as! FlipTableViewCellZero
    UIView.transition(with: deselectedCell, duration: 0.6, options: .transitionFlipFromLeft, animations: nil, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: You don't dequeue a cell anywhere other than in your `cellForRowAt`. In your `didSelect` you need to call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` in order to refresh the cell type.

Comment: @Paulw11 can you help me please come to more detail

Comment: @Sulthan This question was asked first, so it cannot be the duplicate. Please reopen this one and close the other one.

Comment: see this once bro : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24688083/how-can-i-flip-an-ios-uitableviewcell

Comment: @Anbu.karthik i want to flip on click didSelect. suppose, it is showing `0 indexpath` of `FlipTableViewCellZero` defaultly. next i will show `0 indexpath` of `FlipTableViewCellOne` after click `didSect func`. again it come back to show `0 indexPath` of `FlipTableViewCellZero` when i will click second time on `didSect func`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to display your category in two different ways: open and closed.

You're running into problems because you are trying to update the display by dequeueing a new cell in `didSelectRowAt` and `didDeselectRowAt`. This is incorrect.

The proper way to update the display is to call either:

- `tableView.reloadData`, which reloads the entire table view, or
- `tableView.reloadRows(at:with:)`, which reloads just the specified rows

For simplicity, I'm going to use the first option in this example.

Another problem with your code is that you are trying to use a class-level variable `isOpen` to remember the state of your category. This isn't going to work when you have more than one category.

A better approach is to add `isOpen` as a property of your categoryObject class. You set it initially to `false` and then toggle it when the row is tapped. Here is a possible solution:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let categoryObject = arrNewsList[indexPath.section]

    if categoryObject.isOpen {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FlipTableViewCellZero", for: indexPath) as! FlipTableViewCellZero

        cell.profileImage = categoryObject[indexPath.row].textView
        return cell
    }
    else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FlipTableViewCellOne", for: indexPath) as! FlipTableViewCellOne

        cell.newsTextView.text = categoryObject[indexPath.row].details
        return cell
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {    
    let categoryObject = arrNewsList[indexPath.section]
    categoryObject.isOpen = true
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let categoryObject = arrNewsList[indexPath.section]
    categoryObject.isOpen = false
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Now, this doesn't give you the animation you wanted, but it addresses the core problem with your current code.

To do the animation, check into the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614935-reloadrows) for `reloadRows(at:with:)`. Using this method, instead of `reloadData()`, you can animate the change in display of your category.

Comment: Did you add isOpen as a property on your categoryObject class?

Comment: `categoryObject` identifier is invalid